# Securing a pcb to be used in a keyboard to its case

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, keyboard, stability

I'm looking for a way to secure a pcb I will be making for a cherry mx (homemade) keyboard to a case which I'll also be making. Obviously, I don't want the pcb to move. I could use standoffs/screws, but wouldn't the added height between the pcb and case cause the pcb to flex when keys are pressed? Glue/tape seems mega sketch and may mess with conductivity. How is this done on normal (production) keyboards? Advice is much appreciated.

Comment: More than one screw.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How many? What distribution would stop it flexing in the center?

Comment: That would depend on how stiff the PCB is. But at least 6.

Comment: We used a tape from 3M called "vhb", but it's pretty expensive for a one-off, personal project.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I haven't started case design yet. PCB is finished save mounting holes and board outline. Could the scres coincide with legs of the case and sink down into them?

Comment: @fozbstuios  Do you mean something like a small plastic boss (or pedestal) with a screw hole?  That's a legitimate technique.  the dimensions would depend on the material and the size of the screw.  How are you planning to fabricate the enclosure?  Are you going to have it 3D printed?

Comment: @bitsmack VHB is very useful.  You can get a large roll for around $35 on Amazon.  Very helpful.

Comment: @joesacher Yeah, we used it for everything :) Once I took some home and taped a key hook onto my wall. A year layer, when I tried to remove it, it tore the paint and sheetrock away from the wall!

Comment: @bitsmack Would vhb mess with any of my traces electrical properties? (My board is two sided).

Comment: @fozbstuios, I put the info into an answer.  I hope it helps!

Comment: BTW, don't assume that a thicker (and thus stiffer) PCB will be more expensive than a thinner one. This is not always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a previous company, we used VHB 4905 tape by 3M.  You can use it to secure a PCB to an enclosure, and then use it to seal the enclosure, too :)

It has a body thickness of 20mil, so it's pretty compliant.  It's non-conductive (10^16 Ohms/square), and has a breakdown voltage of 630V per mil.  We never saw any issues with using it to stick PCB's to aluminum housings.

If your PCB has RF components, the dielectric constant of any material may detune your rf circuitry...

The datasheet for the entire line of VHB tapes is [here](http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/67100O/vhb-tapes-technical-data.pdf).  Page 7 shows the electrical characteristics.  It's not cheap, but you can get a [short roll](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZCR3ZU) on Amazon for about $17.

As an aside, once I took some home and taped a pewter key hook to my wall. A year layer, when I tried to remove it, the paint and sheetrock tore away before the VHB! Nothing like a little quick spackling as you leave :)

Good luck :)

Comment: All answers are good but I'll go with this as it seems easiest.(albeit least cost effective).

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, you need to use enough standoffs to do the job!

In addition, if you can't put standoffs every place you think you need them, you might need to use one or more "stiffeners" (usually a metal bar with an L-shaped cross-section) that spans between pairs of standoffs and provides extra mechanical support to the PCB. Make sure that components and their connections won't interfere with where the stiffener needs to touch the PCB.

Answer (score 4):

I would put mounting holes and/or supports in the back (for the PCB to press against) on a square grid with 80mm centers, or triangular grid with 100mm centers. Obviously, the numbers are approximate and the grid doesn't have to be dead-on square.

**P.S.** If you post some mechanical drawings, I could critique your design in more detail.